# Specifying web.config without overriding existing one?

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config

In an ASP .NET Core application, there is no default `web.config` file in the project. However, when I run `dotnet publish`, there is a `web.config` file present in the output directory.

But what if I want to modify some web.config values, and have those merged into the published web.config?

Comment: I think it's possible with publish profiles. Have a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.2#run-a-target-before-or-after-publishing) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I just wasn't paying enough attention. If I make a `web.config` file in my project with new properties, it is *merged* into the generated `web.config` on publish.